# what is wrong with this css?

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink

I want to change color of h3 links to red in this code:

```
<div class="news_headline">
    <h3 class="breaking"><a href="#">title</a></h3>
</div>
```

I change css to:

```
a.breaking {
    padding-right: 40px;
    background: url('../images/icons/news_breaking.png') right center no-repeat;
    color: red;
}
```

but it doesnt works!!! it display header as blue! here is css I change:

http://paste2.org/p/1959809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be wrapping the heading tag with the anchor tag http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links

Comment: yes! that is it. thanks! html: <a class="breaking" href="#"><h3>title</h3></a> css: .breaking h3 {
    padding-right: 40px;
    background: url('../images/icons/news_breaking.png') right center no-repeat;
    color: red;
}

Answer (score 7):

change `a.breaking` to `.breaking a` or add the `breaking` class to the anchor element.

Comment: not working. also here is additional css files I use in this page: jquery ui: http://paste2.org/p/1959836 , datepicker: http://paste2.org/p/1959835 , nivoslider: http://paste2.org/p/1959834 + http://paste2.org/p/1959833

Answer (score 2):

`a.breaking` means: an a-element that has a breaking-class like this: `<a class="breaking" href="#">title</a>`

You can bind the style to the h3-element like so:

```
h3.breaking { /* h3 instead of a */
    padding-right: 40px;
    background: url('../images/icons/news_breaking.png') right center no-repeat;
    color: red;
}
```

or you can add the class-attribute to the a-element:

```
<div class="news_headline">
    <h3><a class="breaking" href="#">title</a></h3> <!-- class is in a, not in h3 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `.breaking a {}`. This will then apply the css rules to all elements that have `class='breaking'` or are `<a>` tags.

two great tools for debugging css and javascript are firefox's firebug plugin or chrome's console. These make it easy to see where each element is getting its css from.

Answer (score 0):

you should define the red color also for a:link and a:visited (since you defined a darkblue in your css code, line 10), so try

```
.breaking a {
    padding-right: 40px;
    background: url('../images/icons/news_breaking.png') right center no-repeat;
}


.breaking a, .breaking a:link, .breaking a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```